# in parse pfquery doesn't work

Tags: web-services, parsing, ios7, xcode5, pfquery

PFQuery *queryBankList = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Blood_Bank_Master"];

```
[queryBankList findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *BankObjects, NSError *error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        [aBankInfo addObjectsFromArray:BankObjects];

    } else
    {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit : 
for some reason i believe you spell wrong the class name .
are you sure that your class name is Blood_Bank_Master ?

if not you can check by adding those lines 
NSLog(@" my bank objects %@",BankObjects ) then post what you see in the output.